# Convert base 10 number into base 16

Tags: java

I have to make a class that transforms a given number in base 10 into base 16. Here is my code so far which works BUT i have to do the algorithm MANUALLY, can anybody guide me how can i do it manually ? thank you

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.SourceTree;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by TudorV on 24/06/2016.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        number = scn.nextInt();
       // String string = scn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your number is: " + number);
        String output ="";
        output = Integer.toString(number, 16);
        System.out.println("output is: " + output);



    }

}
```

Comment: The operator % works as modulo-operator, that is, it returns the remainder of an integer division. That's all you need to know for your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Divide your number by 16 `(exp.: 35 / 16 = 2.1875)`.

Step 2: Subtract the integer of the result `(2.1875 - 2 = 0.1875)`.

Step 3: Multiply by 16 `(0.1875 * 16 = 3)`. (Remainder)

Step 4: Repeat step one by dividing the integer of the first result by 16 `(2 / 16 = 0.125)`.

Step 5: Repeat steps 2-4 until the integer is smaller than 16 and was divided by 16 once.

Note every remainder `(3, 2)`. Turn the order around `(2, 3)`. Thats your result: `0x23`

Comment: How to subtract the integer of the result?

Comment: double number;
int remainder = number - (int) number;

Answer (score 0):

- Define an array which has base 16 number. (array)
- Store reminder in list. To get reminder use modulo-operator (%). NOTE: If reminder is greater than 9 then we use character(10 - A, 11 - B ...). For that we have store 16 number in array. We use that array.
- Then number = number/16
- Repeat same thing until number equals to zero
- Then print the list in reverse order or store in stringbuffer and return as a string

Check below code.

```
public static String convertIt(int number) {
    String[] array = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" }; //Define an array which has base 16 number
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(); //list to store reminder
    StringBuffer strB = new StringBuffer();
    while (number != 0) {
        l.add(array[number%16]); //store reminder -- NOTE use array 
        number = number / 16; //change number 
    }
    for (int i = l.size()-1; i > -1; i--) {
        strB.append(l.get(i));
    }
    return strB.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the way you convert decimal to binary. (Or any other base)
Remember how decimal numbers are related to base 10:

Eg: 123

```
1 * 10 ^ 2 + 2 * 10 ^1 + 3 * 10 ^ 0

100 + 20  + 3 = 123
```

To convert it base 16, it should look like

```
7 * 16^1 +  11 * 16^0 = 123
```

Thus it should be represented like `7 11`

Check out the following python code:

```
def convert_base(number, base):
    result = []
    while number > 0:
        result.append(number % base)
        number = number / base
    result.reverse()
    return result

print convert_base(17, 16)
```